# Where to run java exe file using Datagram traffic?

Tags: java, web-hosting, datagram

I have a small exe file (made from Java Runnable jar) which uses datagram traffic.

It takes around 30MB RAM and 10-20 KBps network IO.

The question is where can i run this file 24*7?

-I cannot buy a dedicated machine (Too costly and not required).

-Cheap webhosts dont support datagram traffic .

-Google app engine doesnot support datagrams?

I can put few days to change the language from Java to something else if i can find cheap hosting to run this.

Or is running this from Home the only option ?

Answer (score 1):

With the program using 30MB of ram, 10-20KBps network IO, as long as it doesn't chunk up your CPU cycles, i say run it on your main machine.